# Text inside Doughnut chart using Chart.js and Angular2, Ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, ionic2, chart.js

How can I add a text label inside Doughnut chart using Chart.js and Angular2?
I saw some answers on this topic but none of them are working for me since I am working with Ionic2 app.
This is my simplified code:

```
  import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

    @ViewChild('doughnutCanvas') doughnutCanvas;

    ionViewDidEnter() {

    this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {

      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: this.titles,
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Work',
          data: this.times,
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)'
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#36A2EB"
          ]
        }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating / registering a plugin before generating the chart and you could create the plugin in the following way ...

```
Chart.plugins.register({
    beforeDraw: function(chart) {
        var data = chart.data.datasets[0].data;
        var sum = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);
        var width = chart.chart.width,
            height = chart.chart.height,
            ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
        ctx.restore();
        var fontSize = (height / 10).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + "px Arial";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        var text = sum,
            textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
            textY = height / 2;
        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
        ctx.save();
    }
});
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
// register plugin
Chart.plugins.register({
    beforeDraw: function(chart) {
        var data = chart.data.datasets[0].data;
        var sum = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);
        var width = chart.chart.width,
            height = chart.chart.height,
            ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
        ctx.restore();
        var fontSize = (height / 10).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + "px Arial";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        var text = sum,
            textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
            textY = height / 2;
        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
        ctx.save();
    }
});

// generate chart
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: And how to make it responsive to changes?

Comment: @ChrisK.um.. what changes? chart size?

Comment: I want to display the sum of chart data, so if the data is changed I want text to display a new sum.

Comment: I would like to do that but it didn't work for me :(

Comment: @ChrisK. what's the issue? :/

Comment: Data in the text field is set just once at the beginning and isn't refreshing when chart updates.

Comment: how do i do it for two doughnut chats on my page? right now somehow it generically attaches the same center text two both the charts

Answer (score 1):

If you guys are trying to add legend.
You should change the height by using

```
height = (chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2
textY = height;
```

using the chartArea is more correct.
Otherwise your text would ignore the height of legend and be located in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who is using `ng2-charts^2.4.2"` the registration of the inline plugin can be done via the `baseChart` directive's input attribute `[plugins]`.

First you have to define a `plugins` property holding and array of plugins. (You could also register your official plugins there `plugins = [ChartDataLabels, {/*inline plugin*/}]` )

For correct label **placement inside the doughnut** chart you have to take into account the position of the legend, which could be above, below or at the left or right **side**. So I tweaked @GRUNT and @ginagigo123 answers into an **ultimate answer** that is based on the following calculations

```js
let textX = Math.round(((chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
let textY = Math.round((chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2);
```

**compoonent.ts**

```js
  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective, { static: true })
  chartNgWrapper: BaseChartDirective;

  plugins = [
    {
      beforeDraw: function (chart: any) {
        let data = chart.data.datasets[0].data;
        let sum = (data as number[]).reduce(function (a, b) {
          return a + b;
        }, 0);
        let width = chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right,
          height = chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom,
          ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
        ctx.restore();
        let fontSize = (height / 10).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + 'px Arial';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
        let text = sum,
          textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
          textY = height / 2;
        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
        ctx.save();
      },
    },
  ];
```

In case you are making an app that can switch **language writing mode**, you have to get the current `rtl` (right-to-left) value from somewhere (mine is defined in the legend) and add or substract based on it:

```js
   let textX = chart.legend.options.rtl
       ? Math.round((width + ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2)
       : Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
```

If you are manipulation the writing direction via an html element's `dir` attribute (`<app-root  dir="ltr">`) you can also get the current language writing mode from `chart.ctx.direction`, in this case it returns `'rtl'` or `'ltr'` strings

**component.html**

```html
<canvas
  baseChart
  #chart
  [datasets]="doughnutChartData"
  [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
  [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
  [options]="options"
  [plugins]="plugins"
>
</canvas>
```